# How to expand a class object

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, ado.net

I want to get this right so I oversimplified it.

As is, this will return nulls in all three textboxes.

I know the "foreach" is incorrect.

Could someone enlighten me on how to expand a class object.

Default.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<dataclass> returnedData = Getdata();
        foreach (var dataclass0 in returnedData)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = dataclass0.item1;
            TextBox2.Text = dataclass0.item2;
            TextBox3.Text = dataclass0.item3;
        }
    }
    public static List<dataclass> Getdata()
    {
        List<dataclass> returndata = new List<dataclass>();
        dataclass dc = new dataclass();
        dc.item1 = "a";
        dc.item2 = "b";
        dc.item3 = "c";
        returndata.Add(dc);
        return returndata;
    }
```

Class1.cs

```
public class dataclass
{
    public string item1 { get; set; }
    public string item2 { get; set; }
    public string item3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The `TextBox.Text` _never_ returns `null`, it returns `""` even if you assign null. But in this case it clearly has the values `a`, `b` and `c`. But why do you use a `List<T>` if you just want to assign a single value to a `TextBox`? The loop would just overwrite the last value if there were multiple items.

Comment: How do you define dataclass0 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will build 3 strings (one for each TextBox) and later assign them to their corresponding Text properties.
It uses `StringBuilder` to optimize concatenation. `AppendLine` is useful to keep spaced apart the different concatenated values: `.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ", ")` will later replace line breaks with ", "; if you don't need to space apart the values, simply remove `.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ", ")` and replace `AppendLine` with `Append`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sbText1 = new StringBuilder();
    var sbText2 = new StringBuilder();
    var sbText3 = new StringBuilder();

    var returnedData = Getdata();
    foreach (var dataclass0 in returnedData)
    {
        sbText1.AppendLine(dataclass0.item1);
        sbText2.AppendLine(dataclass0.item2);
        sbText3.AppendLine(dataclass0.item3);
    }

    TextBox1.Text = sbText1.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, ", ");
    TextBox2.Text = sbText2.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, ", ");
    TextBox3.Text = sbText3.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, ", ");
}
```

Regards,
Daniele.

Comment: I am not sure how stringbuilder works but the textboxes were empty.

Comment: StringBuilder simply avoids reallocating String object with every concatenation: it is a better way to concatenate strings, but is not necessarily the way to go; it is suitable for concatenation of many strings, as could be your case.

Comment: About the textboxes being empty, I can argue it could be a problem with the page refresh: Have you debug-checked the Text property at the end of the method execution?